# What are tasty sushi combinations?

Tags: the-sushi-spinnery

In Sushi Spinnery, I can get my chefs to create new and different kinds of sushi.

Problem is, I have no idea what ingredients work well together, so I make really terrible choices, which make yucky sushi and then my customers all leave.

What goes well together, so I can make tasty sushi and keep my customers happy, and win contests?

Comment: This question is off topic and should be moved to [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) :]

Comment: Steve V, No, This is an offical Kairosoft game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get award winning sushis for the contest or to please your customers, you need to do the following:

- for contests you need to use the right ingredients for the 4 main categories, each ingredient has stats in flavour, texture, aroma and color. Each ingredient has statistics in each of these 4 categories and if the contest has '+++' in flavour you need to choose an ingredient with a lot of flavour.
- ideally you want to choose ingredients that please the group/sex age of the jury, if the jury is all female youth, then you gain extra point if you have '+' in these social categories.
- train a chef (two chefs later on) with high prep and third skills: preparation allows you to get better stats and the third skill allows you to find better ingredients when you are offered to spend sushi coins
- choose ingredients which have a compatibility of A (or B if you cannot find A)

You can find a full list of stats for each ingredients and their compatibilities on this page:  http://adeptgamer.com/forum/pages/the-sushi-spinnery-guide/

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got so far:

- Amaebi + Mayo + Kizanori will have grade A compatibility for starting the game
- Tamago + Kizanori + Rock Salt will have grade A too (you can also use sweet sauce)

When you have unlock ika:

- ika + salt rock + sweet sauce that will give you pretty good sushi

These 3 sushi will win you contest up to 2 stars I believe. Just be sure to check who's the judges and apply the correct sushi

Answer (score 1):

Tama Amaebi Maki is one of the best dishes I have made. The chef I used had 140-150 discern. Adding a few price seeds, quality seeds also soy sauce will boost it significantly.

Note that for this dish is used a Max seed, and a colour seed. 
The Chef I used for this is Pony Inzuka at =level 5

Sells well with Female: Kids youth Adults and elderly all with ++ or above.
not as well with male characters. Only kids like it +

```
Energy   56
Prep     55
Discern1 165
Service  86
```

The final dish rating

```
Flavour     : 4-5
Texture     : 3-4
Aroma       : 7-9
Colour/color: 9-14
```

Also the chef I used has made Amaebi for a several times. If it is your first time developing this dish, your taste for this dish and price should be around 7-10, 23-28 respectively. The Contest I won with this dish are

- Company Contest
- Birthday contest
- Mermaid Contest

The dish should be blue striped/green, if you did not make it in the first time, try cooking more amaebi dishes before attempting this one again. I chose to make this dish because the season is right, I used around 70 sushi coins. When you go to pick the ingredients, the quality of it should be "legendary".

- Prep time: D*
- Taste    : 7=8*
- Price    : 20-30

One final note, Amaebi is one of the easiest but most profitable dishes you can make. There are a lot of combinations for Amaebi, but this is the best I've made so far.
Amaebi works with these items quite well:

- Tamago
- Amaebi
- Salt
- Simichi
- Mayo
- Sweet Sauce

Answer (score 1):

Base Hamachi should have overall boost pretty good already, since Hamachi itself is all seasons and has ++ most for youths and even at least 2 ++ for all others too.

I guess Nigiri Hamachi , Neriume , Lemon does pretty well and is overall season too.

There are better combinations but I haven't unlocked yet.

Answer (score 0):

My tasty sushi so far is uni + uni + daikon oroshi.

If you add some quality seed and price seed it would be better

I think hamachi is delicious too...

Answer (score -1):

When you pick how many sushi coins to use, go for the most in order to get the best of the best. Not only do you get extra points towards the four, but you also get experience points, which upgrade the sushi as well.

Every contest has different requirements, so it depends on which contest you want the sushi for.

Comment: This really doesn't answer what I am asking. I understand how contests work, I am mostly just looking for what to combine to make sushi that is better than average, and gets high points in the most categories.